# Jest - toBeNull() and not.toBeNull() return both false

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using React, Jest, and React-testing-library. I want to check that some elements are not rendered on my screen.

```
filterElementsNotPresent.forEach(
    ({ name }) => {
      const nameLabel = queryByText(name);      
      expect(nameLabel).toBeNull();
```

The result is the following:
[image]

So I tried putting the not at the start:

```
filterElementsNotPresent.forEach(
        ({ name }) => {
          const nameLabel = queryByText(name);      
          expect(nameLabel).not.toBeNull();
```

And the result is:

[image]

I am really lost. Can someone give me some help with this?

Comment: You're in the middle of a `.forEach`, so some indices of the array fail on the `toBeNull` check, others fail on the `not.toBeNull` check. No individual element is going to fail both of them. Without knowing how the array was created, we can't tell you much more. Perhaps try logging out the entire array, and see which index of the array has the unexpected element.